# How to not allow an error message to occupy space in the DOM if error is not displayed?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a simple Login page where I show a error message on failed authentication. I have a div with some classes applied , and inside it I display the error message through a `<label.../>`.

Now when the page is loaded for the first time, there is obviously no error message and thus there is an blank space left.

What I want is if there is no error message, the div should occupy no space or should be hidden and should only show if there is any text(error message) inside the div.

Here is my HTML :

```
<form id="login-form" action="authenticate.php" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
         <label style="color:red"><?php if(isset($error)) echo $error; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
          <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login_error'])){
        if($_GET['login_error']== 'true'){
            $error = "Email and/or Password was incorrect! Please try again!";
        }   
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it so that it calls out all the HTML in the php function. Like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login_error'])){
        if($_GET['login_error']== 'true'){
            $error = '<div class="form-group text-center">';
            $error .= '<label style="color:red">Email and/or Password was incorrect! Please try again!</label>';
            $error .= '</div>';
        }   
    }
?>

<form id="login-form" action="authenticate.php" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IS HERE -->
    <?php if(isset($error)) echo $error; ?>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
          <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I got confused whether this can happen or not .. I am new to PHP ..anyways! Thank you for the guidance !Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change the content of the if statement to include the entire element, like so:

```
<?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
<div class="form-group text-center">
     <label style="color:red"><?php echo $error; ?></label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```